# Beer n Brewery Statistics - Any Sources for Production, Consumption, Number of Breweries, etc. per Country?

Tags: breweries

Looking for sources for beer n brewery statistics such as production in hl per year, consumption, consumption per capita, number of breweries (macro, regional, micro, brewpubs, and so on) etc. ideally for all countries in the world. Any insight and help appreciated.

Disclaimer: I'm the project lead of the beer.csv project that collects (open, free) [beer statistics](https://github.com/beercsv/statistics) in the CSV (comma-separated values) format.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bit of statistics on Norway [here](http://www.garshol.priv.no/blog/277.html).

In the US the [Brewers' Association](http://www.brewersassociation.org/) publishes statistics. Generally that's where you'll find statistics world-wide. [Here](http://www.drikkeglede.no/tall_og_fakta/) is corresponding statistics for Norway.

Trawling through the "Beer_in_Xxx" pages on Wikipedia may provide you with more pointers.

For historical data, [European Beer Guide](http://www.europeanbeerguide.net/) is a great source.

Comment: Thanks. Great sources. Will add some stats to the beer.csv repo. Cheers. Skål. Prost.